# Is it possible to add touch event to CAEmitterLayer

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add touch gesture to CAEmitterLayer, Could you please explain is it possible add touch gesture to CAEmitterLayer or there are another option.

Comment: You can always add gesture recognizer to the enclosing view which hold the emitter layer

Comment: @ZellB. Thank you